# How to list all objects in a Scala object?

Tags: scala, reflection, singleton

So, I have defined several objects in `my_object`. 
I'm able to make `import my_package._` and access them all, or I can do 
`import my_package.{Obj1, Obj2}`.

I want to list them all and get their names. I can do `val my_list = List(Obj1, Obj2).map(_.toString())`, but listing them manually is a no-go.

How could I produce `my_list` without declaring the objects individually?

Comment: What do you mean with _"list"_ them? It is just for development purposes, like you want to know what it is there? Or do you need that functionality in your production code?

Comment: I edited the question for clarity, but what I mean is that I want that list for production (I mean, nothing critical, it is just a DataBricks widget list, but anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider reflection and [`isModule`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Symbols$SymbolApi.html#isModule:Boolean) method

> Does this symbol represent the definition of a module (i.e. it results
>   from an object definition?).

for example

```
object Qux {
  object Bar1
  object Bar2
  object Bar3
}

scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  .classSymbol(Qux.getClass)
  .info
  .members
  .filter(_.isModule)
  .map(_.name.toString)
  .toList
```

gives

```
res1: List[String] = List(Bar3, Bar2, Bar1)
```

Comment: What the hell, that is literally exactly what I was looking for, I just had to replace the name of the Object. Absolutely thank you.

Do you have any doc or tutorial to point out?

I mean, `.info`, `.members`, `classSymbol`... how can I find about those guys?

I just learned about the `.getClass().getMethods()`, and I'm wondering what else is there for me.


PS. `Qux`? I've seen `Foo`, `Bar`, and stuff, but that is new to me lol

Comment: @LucasLima you need to search for **reflection**, However, I word of warning, reflection is slow, unsafe and usually not encouraged in Scala. Usually, there are other ways to solve the problem, but I am glad this works for you :)

Comment: Thank you! As I said, this is more of a side project - I just need to list some 15 options in a dropdown widget, and that is it. Fits perfectly. Thank you for the warning and advice, though.

Comment: @LucasLima [Reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html), [Metasyntactic_variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable).

Comment: @MarioGalic, can you please point out where exactly is the method `.members`? I searched all over the docs, but cannot, for the life in me, figure out where is it. In fact, I'm having a hard time understanding even what kind of object do I get after calling the `.info` function. I'm trying to thoroughly understand this series of operations, step by step, and I'm having a hard time on that part...